# What is the better practice for page scroll event in react: addEventListener() vs. Create a component wrapper all contents and use onScroll prop

Tags: reactjs

What is the better practice for handling page scroll event in react?

A. `addEventListener()` in all components need page scroll event

B. Create a component as the wrapper of the page, and use onScroll to handle the event

C. Any other better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to observe whether is an element in screen, [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) can be used also.